# After edit crontab stopped performing

Tags: cron, debian

I had one cronjob:

```
*/10 * * * ruby /home/pi/GIT/Zonky/Ruby/getUserLoans.rb
```

Everything worked just fine.

I added a second one:

```
*/5 * * * python /home/pi/Crypto/Crypto_cron.py
```

Since the edit, cron doesn't do any of the two jobs.
I used the following command:

```
cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i CRON
```

On the attached screenshot please note:

- last cron run of ruby command at 7AM
- Editing crontab for the first time at 7:05
- No ruby nor python command since then
  [image]

I also restarted cron daemon, which didn't help.
I have no idea where to look for an answer.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

My problem was the existing command.
It worked for months - which gave me the confidence that it is correct, while it **was** correct

I use vim and probably due to some reckless use of hotkeys I managed to broke the existing command. That's the issue here.

So both commands are wrong, there should be 5 time parameters (e.g. stars) and I only have 4.